# Connection problem localhost7474 in neo4j for a specific DBMS

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am running a dblp citation DBMS in neo4j but localhost refused to connect, while any other sample DBMS connects and worked smoothly. [screen shot for the error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZfFm.png)

Comment: do you have any errors?

Comment: there is no error apparently.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Neo4j is not running.
It takes some time(few seconds) to become available after start/restart.

You can check the status of neo4j by running this command (**To run all the commands open cmd in admin mode**):

> neo4j status

It will output **Neo4j is running** if neo4j is up.

If it's running, You can also check if it's running on port 7474 by the command:

> netstat -ano | findstr :7474

If this doesn't output anything on screen then check the port in the config file.

If Noej4 is not running you can start with this command:

> neo4j start

Please refer to the screenshot for details: [image]

Comment: its running and its working with other databases but I am stuck only on dblp citation neo4j database

Comment: You can check neo4j.log file for logs If you don't understand you can share last few lines here.